# Web App Azure Portal - Key Vault Reference shows not connected

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-configuration

We have configured the azure Key Vault reference via azure portal configuration settings. But the key vault reference sometimes shows tick and sometimes cross (x).

Can someone confirm if this is going to impact the web app or is it just portal not being able to connect to Key Vault reference?

And whether there's way to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled MSI in Azure app service and configure the "Get" secret permission for the MSI in Azure key vault. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: is this happening only today? there is an outage

Comment: Yep MSU is enabled. Happens randomly, not just today

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the App Service in the Azure Portal, select `Diagnose and solve problems`, then on the subsequent panel search for "Key Vault", there is a diagnostic that will evaluate your Key Vault config references, and tell you where there may be a misconfiguration.

Comment: On debug I can see -  "No errors related to Key Vault references found"  

But, portal still shows - "x Key vault Reference"

Where x is error

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app service? That has helped me in the past with Key Vault app config issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have tick sign to make it work. In order to have keyvault reference set correctly, there are two things you need to check.

**1. Allow App Service IP**

This is needed if your keyvault is open to only selected networks.

Go to App Service -> Networking -> Outbound Traffic -> IP addresses. Unless you have used [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) or enabled [NAT Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) and [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration), your app service should have a long list of outbound IP addresses.

In Keyvault -> Networking -> Firewalls and Virtual Networks -> Add these outbound IP addresses

**2. Add Access Policy**

In Keyvault -> Access Policy -> Add Access Policy
[image]